# How can I make a bold horizontal rule under each section title?

Tags: sectioning, rules

I want to place a long bold `\hrule`-type line under the `\section` to make it more distinctive. How can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; the optional argument for `\titlerule` allows you to control the rule "thickness":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And for the width? Because default is \textwidth...

Comment: @FormlessCloud can you please expand your question a little? I don't understand what you mean. Do you want the line only to cover the title and not the whole text width?

Comment: Sure, for example, if I would a \titlerule that have the width of for example .5\textwidth how can I do this? Because if I type only \titlerule that command give me automatically a rule that fit the entire width of my page. In sinthesys I would to adjust the length (or I can call it width, how you prefer) of my line.

Comment: @FormlessCloud Ah, I see. In that case, instead of `[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]` you can use something like `[\vskip-10pt{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.8pt}}}]` (adjusting the vertical skip, if necessary). Changing the settings for the `\makebox` you can also obtain lines wider than the `\textwidth`.

Comment: This does not work if one uses `\usepackage{sectsty}`. I use this package for setting the color of the section. Alternatively, just set `\color{red}` within the `\titleformat` command.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina How do I remove numbers in section?