# How to place a center aligned rule on the left of a section title?

Tags: sectioning, rules

[image: The proposed effect]

How can I achieve this effect? 
I have tried the following code:

```
\parbox[c]{3.5cm}{\color{NavyBlue}{\rule{90px}{7px}}} \parbox[c]{6cm}{\section*{Section Title}}
```

But the rule is not center aligned with the title because `\section` command contain some extra space below the text.

And I had tried a alternative:

```
\parbox[c]{3.5cm}{\color{NavyBlue}{\rule{90px}{7px}}} \parbox[c]{6cm}{\Large{Section Title}}
```

Although this time the rule is center aligned, but if I add text below the title, the line space would be too small.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Should the rule hang in the margin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that there was a related question yesterday [How can I make a bold horizontal rule under each section title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/how-can-i-make-a-bold-horizontal-rule-under-each-section-title)  Following that example, I seem to be able to create the effect that you desire:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{NavyBlue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\parbox{10em}{\rule{10em}{0.5em}}}{1em}{}[{}]

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

Random stuff

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd never heard of the `titlesec` package before.  Looks like it has some very nice tools for modifying the look and feel of sections.

Comment: Don't use `px` for the units. It hasn't a fixed value and changes in the preamble might modify it. And I don't think that the `\parbox` is really needed (use the optional arguments to `\rule).

Comment: @egreg.   Thanks.  I was just following lhhNJU's example as closely as possible.  I used the `parbox` to force vertical centering with the section title.  I know you can write `\rule[1ex]{10em}{0.5ex}` but is there a way to tell rule to center with text on the same line?

Comment: Just play with the "raise" argument; possibly something like `0.4ex`

Comment: I just noticed I used a non-fixed value length again.  @egreg.  Are you suggesting that I doing sometihng like `\rule[3pt]{2in}{3pt}`?

Comment: `ex` is good, as it depends on the current font, which is *really* what you want.

Comment: Using `\rule[0.3ex]{10em}{0.5ex}` works fine!

Comment: @A.Ellett I wonder how I can find documentation for package `titlesec` ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a variation in which the rule hangs in the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{NavyBlue}}{}{0em}{\llap{\rule[.5ex]{90pt}{4pt}\hspace*{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. But what I intend is to put the rule in the text region.

Comment: @lhhNJU OK, but you should consider what would happen if a section title spans more than one line.