# How to make a rule under each section title with KOMA-Script?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

This question is more or less a duplicate of this [similarly named question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/how-can-i-make-a-bold-horizontal-rule-under-each-section-title), but is not exactly the same. I also want to place a horizontal rule below each section title (exactly like in the linked question). The answer to this existing question only shows how to achieve this using the `titlesec` package.

However I am using the KOMA-Script class `scrreprt`, and it is not recommended to use `titlesec` and KOMA-Script together, as `titlesec` [breaks several KOMA-Script features](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec) and KOMA-Script complains about that in a warning.

It appears that `\DeclareSectionCommand` can only change the vertical skip before / after the section title. Finally there exist commands like `\At@startsection` to add something *before*  the section title, but nothing to add anything *after* the section title.

Is there any way to make KOMA-Script print a rule after the section title without using the `titlesec` package?

A small MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{The first chapter}
    \section{A nice section}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

Desired result (rule doesn't have to be red):

[image: result]

Comment: What about multiline titles?

Comment: I don't plan on using multiline titles, but of course it would be nicer if that worked like single-line titles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will be possible with [KOMA-Script version 3.19](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) or newer. There is a newcommand `\sectionlinesformat` that can be redefined to insert the line after a section title.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2015/09/15]% needs Version 3.19 or newer

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
      \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\par%
      \kern-.75\ht\strutbox\rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}%
    }%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}% 
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only dummy text
\begin{document}
    \chapter{The first chapter}
    \section{A nice section}
    \Blindtext[2]
    \addsec{A nice section without number}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great, this was exactly what I was looking for. After manually updating to the newest KOMA-Script version, this works nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this might be a start.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\let\svsection\section
\def\section#1{\svsection{#1}\noindent\smash{\rule[3ex]{\textwidth}{2pt}}\par%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\noindent}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{The first chapter}
    \section{A nice section}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you for your help. This solution comes with the advantage that it also works for standard-classes (report ...)