# Prevent page break between section and subsection with \hrule and \hfill between

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I'm among many it seems that is trying to prevent an inappropriate pagebreak. In this case, I'm getting a pagebreak between my section and subsequent subsection. I know if I remove the `\hrule` and `\hfill` then LaTeX will pull them together, but with the line between, the subsection is orphaned to the next page.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lots\\of\\text\\here\\to\\fill\\space\\so\\that\\the\\new\\section\\is\\right\\near\\the\\bottom.\\
Almost\\there.\\
I\\bet\\there's\\a\\better\\way\\to\\do\\this...\\
Hopefully\\someday\\I'll\\know\\how\\but\\for\\now\\I'm\\stuck\\with\\this\\mess.\\

\section*{Section title}
\hrule
\hfill
\subsection*{\underline{Subsection title}}

\end{document}
```

[image: break]

I don't want a hard-coded `\pagebreak` right before the section because the amount of text above it will vary. I tried wrapping all four lines in `\begin{samepage}` and `\end{samepage}` but it didn't seem to help.

How can I make sure the subsection is not orphaned on the next page?

Comment: Why the \hfill? And is the \hrule part of the section layout?

Comment: When `\hfill` is absent and the whole thing is not straddling the page break, then the subsection is too close to the `\hrule` line and it looks ugly. I have the `\hrule` line in the first place to make the underline across the whole page under all the section headers. It's aesthetically pleasing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not what I’d recommend: if you want to customize the appearance of sectioning titles, use, for example, the `titlesec` package.  However, even if you insist for a do-it-yourself solution, there’s no need to have recourse to the `minipage` environment: it suffices to insert penalty items at the right spots, which can be done by means of the `\nobreak` commands.  There is one further point to note, though: the fact that you say `\hfill` causes TeX to start a new paragraph, and this resets the `\if@nobreak` switch to `\iffalse`, so that a penalty of -300 is inserted above the `\subsection` title.  To put it simply, you make TeX think that a paragraph intervene between the `\section` and the `\subsection`, so it will no longer treat the two as consecutive sectioning titles, between which a page break is prohibited.  If you are saying `\hfill` in order to get an empty line in the output, please note that this is *not* the way to go.

Here is an example of how your code could be fixed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lots\\of\\text\\here\\to\\fill\\space\\so\\that\\the\\new\\section\\is\\right\\near\\the\\bottom.\\
Almost\\there.\\
I\\bet\\there's\\a\\better\\way\\to\\do\\this...\\
Hopefully\\someday\\I'll\\know\\how\\but\\for\\now\\I'm\\stuck\\with\\this\\mess.\\

\makeatletter

\section*{Section title}
\hrule
% \hfill % why do you use "\hfill" here?
\nobreak\vspace{\baselineskip} % is it this what you want?
\subsection*{\underline{Subsection title}}
Some text after the title.

% \showboxbreadth = 1000
% \showboxdepth = 10
% \showlists

\end{document}
```

But, I repeat, don’t do that: use `titlesec`.

Comment: For others searching, this answer helped me figure out how to use titlesec to get my line: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/how-can-i-make-a-bold-horizontal-rule-under-each-section-title